# Why this eBPF code crashes on large amount traffics?

Tags: ebpf

I'm trying to setup a network filter which strips the VLan tags at tc ingress(`tc filter add dev ethx ingress bpf da obj...`) and adds the same VLan tags at route egress(`ip route add default encap bpf headroom 14 xmit obj... dev ethx table xxx`), according to the TCP 4-tuples.

Since the absence of the L2 header at route egress, I call `bpf_skb_change_head` to add the L2 header for the skb, as the following:

```
unsigned short headers[7];
memcpy(headers, pm->p_s_mac, 6);                                  //fill the source mac from previous
memcpy(headers + 3, pm->p_d_mac, 6);                              //fill the destination mac from previous
headers[6] = eth_p_proto;                                         //set the proto type to ipv4(0x0800)
bpf_skb_change_head(skb, sizeof(headers), 0);                     //reserve the space for mac header
bpf_skb_store_bytes(skb, 0, (void *)headers, sizeof(headers), 0); //fill the mac header
bpf_redirect(skb->ifindex, 0);                                    //send to egress NIC directly
```

The codes above work well in most environments, but when the traffic exceeds 6~7Gbps(10Gbps totally) on single NIC, the whole system will panic & reboot without any useful output info. By commenting some of these functions, I can sure the crash was caused by `bpf_skb_change_head`. Does anyone know the issue or give any advices?

Comment: What kernel are you running? Did you check your syslogs for any kernel stacktraces? That shouldn't happen and is very likely a bug in your kernel.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, I have tried the kernel 5.4.124, 5.4.144 and 5.10.40 with Debian systems, there also have the same crashes, without any output to syslog or console.